# HibernateTemplate can't save entry - Constraint Violation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem trying to insert a new entry in a table. This table is a duplicate of another with the same columns. The original table updates fine. But I have this error with the duplicated table (adhesion_resumen_tc_hist):

```
2020-11-21 19:56:09 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL:92 - insert into adhesion_resumen_tc_hist (ADHESION_RESUMEN_TC_HIST_ID, email, estado, fecha_alta, usuario_id, hash_tarjeta, origen) values (SEQ_ADHESION_RESUMEN_HIST_TC.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-11-21 19:56:09 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:127 - SQL Error: 1, SQLState: 23000
2020-11-21 19:56:09 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:129 - Invalid argument(s) in call
2020-11-21 19:56:09 ERROR ar.com.demo.batch.record.writer.FileRecordWriter:93 - could not prepare statement


<hibernate-mapping>


<class name="ar.com.demo.batch.domain.AdhesionResumenTCHist" table="adhesion_resumen_tc_hist">
    <id name="idAdhHist" type="long" column="ADHESION_RESUMEN_TC_HIST_ID">
        <generator class="sequence-identity">
            <param name="sequence">SEQ_ADHESION_RESUMEN_HIST_TC</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="email" column="email" type="string"/>
    <property name="estado" column="estado" type="string"/>
    <property name="fechaAlta" column="fecha_alta" type="timestamp"/>
    <many-to-one name="usuario" column="usuario_id" lazy="false" cascade="all"
                 class="ar.com.demo.batch.domain.Usuario"/>

    <many-to-one name="tarjetaCred" column="hash_tarjeta" lazy="false"
                 cascade="all" class="ar.com.demo.batch.domain.TarjetaCredito"/>
    <property name="origen" column="origen" type="string"/>
</class>
```

I checked the arguments and there aren't any nulls. So maybe is a problema with my mapping, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying almost everything. I added to the table ID the schema.
table="usr_cuenta.adhesion_resumen_tc_hist"
And now it works. I don't know why it mess with the table "usr_cuenta.adhesion_resumen_tc" they have different ID's.
That was my solution.